# NPM module is not able to import after CSS updates

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-publish

I had to make CSS changes to an NPM module I made.
However, after making some changes I am not able to resolve the NPM module after I made sure it is installed. I made no changes to my index.js in the module and I don't see what is breaking it all of a sudden.

```
 Can't resolve 'gatsby-ui-components' in '/Users/spacemonky/Code/sad-store/src/layouts'
```

the import layout.js:

```
import { ReponsiveLogoNavBar } from 'gatsby-ui-components'
```

index.js in gatsby-ui-components:

```
/*
  Export with named export to be able to pull in from library
*/

export { ReponsiveLogoNavBar } from './components/Navigation/ReponsiveLogoNavBar'
export { HeroSection } from './components/Sections/HeroSection'
export { SlantedSections } from './components/Sections/SlantedSections'
export { CallToAction } from './components/Sections/CallToAction'
export { BasicSitemapFooter } from './components/Footers/BasicSitemapFooter'
export { CurvedSection } from './components/Sections/CurvedSection'
export { FixedNavWrapper } from './components/Wrappers/FixedNavWrapper'
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-ui-components",
  "version": "0.0.20",
  "description": "Gatsby components for website ui",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir dist --ignore **/__tests__ && cp -r src/css dist && cp README.md dist && cp package.json dist",
    "storybook": "start-storybook",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby",
    "components",
    "react",
    "ui",
    "design"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/stcalica/gatsby-components.git"
  },
  "author": "Kyle Calica",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.2.8",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.2.8",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries": "^2.7.19",
    "babel-preset-gatsby-package": "^0.2.12",
    "css-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.18.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My package.json in my NPM module points to index.js by itself. It should point to src/index.js

```
  "main": "src/index.js",
```